How to use associative array in Bash to get the current time in multiple locations?
I want to create a Bash script that outputs the following:
Chile: 03:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Tierra Del Fuego: 03:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Falkland Islands: 03:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands: 04:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
UTC: 06:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Africa: 08:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Port Alfred, Iles Crozet: 10:46am, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Western Australia: 14:46pm, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Australia: 16:16pm, Friday, 27 September, 2024
VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia: 16:46pm, Friday, 27 September, 2024
New Zealand: 18:46pm, Friday, 27 September, 2024

I have managed to do this so far using the following code:
#Chile
location="America/Santiago"
label="Chile"
time=$(TZ=$location date "+%H:%M%p")
date=$(TZ=$location date "+%A, %d %B, %Y")
echo "$label: $time, $date"

...and then just having multiple blocks of that same code, with location and label changed as necessary.
This is ok, but it's a 103-line file. I want to learn how to use associative arrays to achieve the same task for no reason other than simply to learn.
I have created the array itself as follows:
# Declare an associative array
declare -A locationsArray

# Add elements to the associative array

locationsArray[America/Santiago]="Chile"
locationsArray[America/Argentina/Ushuaia]="Tierra Del Fuego"
locationsArray[Atlantic/Stanley]="Falkland Islands"
locationsArray[Atlantic/South_Georgia]="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
locationsArray[Etc/UTC]="UTC"
locationsArray[Africa/Johannesburg]="South Africa"
locationsArray[Asia/Dubai]="Port Alfred, Iles Crozet"
locationsArray[Australia/Perth]="Western Australia, Australia"
locationsArray[Australia/Adelaide]="South Australia, Australia"
locationsArray[Australia/Melbourne]="VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia"
locationsArray[Pacific/Auckland]="New Zealand"

Now I just need to be able to take a key from the array and its associated value (e.g. "America/Santiago" and "Chile"), and iterate through the entire array using the above code as a template.
How can I go about doing this?
Thank you.

This question is similar to: Associative Arrays in Shell Scripts. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Modifying OP's current code to use OP's associative array:
for location in "${!locationsArray[@]}"
do
    td=$(TZ="$location" date "+%H:%M%p, %A, %d %B, %Y")
    echo "${locationsArray[$location]}: ${td}"
done

This generates:
Port Alfred, Iles Crozet: 17:27PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
New Zealand: 01:27AM, Saturday, 28 September, 2024
Western Australia, Australia: 21:27PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
UTC: 13:27PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Australia, Australia: 22:57PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Chile: 10:27AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands: 11:27AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia: 23:27PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Falkland Islands: 10:27AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Tierra Del Fuego: 10:27AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Africa: 15:27PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024

NOTES:

as alluded to in Stéphane's answer you can't (easily) control the order in which associative array entries are processed
this is not an exact match to OP's expected output due to inconsistencies in the inputs/outputs, eg, for input #1 South Australia, Australia the expected output #2 South Australia strips the country, while for input #2  VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia the expected output #2 VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia does not strip the country; OP will need to provide the rules for if/when to strip strings from the input, or update the question to insure inputs and outputs match


Modifying the above code to use a variation of Stéphane's bash / printf call:
printf -v now "%(%s)T"                               # obtain current epoch (seconds), store in variable "now"

for location in "${!locationsArray[@]}"
do
    TZ="$location" printf '%s: %(%H:%M%p, %A, %d %B, %Y)T\n' "${locationsArray[$location]}" "$now"
done

This generates:
Port Alfred, Iles Crozet: 17:45PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
New Zealand: 01:45AM, Saturday, 28 September, 2024
Western Australia, Australia: 21:45PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
UTC: 13:45PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Australia, Australia: 23:15PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Chile: 10:45AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands: 11:45AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia: 23:45PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Falkland Islands: 10:45AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Tierra Del Fuego: 10:45AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Africa: 15:45PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024


To print the results in a particular order OP could switch to a normal array while making sure to populate the array in the same order as the desired output, eg:
        # "location=label"; ordered by label

locations=(
        "America/Santiago=Chile"
        "Atlantic/Stanley=Falkland Islands"
        "Pacific/Auckland=New Zealand"
        "Asia/Dubai=Port Alfred, Iles Crozet"
        "Africa/Johannesburg=South Africa"
        "Australia/Adelaide=South Australia, Australia"
        "Atlantic/South_Georgia=South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
        "America/Argentina/Ushuaia=Tierra Del Fuego"
        "Etc/UTC=UTC"
        "Australia/Melbourne=VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia"
        "Australia/Perth=Western Australia, Australia"
)

printf -v now "%(%s)T"

for ((i=0; i<${#locations[@]}; i++))
do
    IFS="=" read -r location label <<< "${locations[i]}"      # split on "=" delimiter into variables "location" and "label"
    TZ="$location" printf '%s: %(%H:%M%p, %A, %d %B, %Y)T\n' "$label" "$now"
done

This generates:
Chile: 10:57AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Falkland Islands: 10:57AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
New Zealand: 01:57AM, Saturday, 28 September, 2024
Port Alfred, Iles Crozet: 17:57PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Africa: 15:57PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Australia, Australia: 23:27PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands: 11:57AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Tierra Del Fuego: 10:57AM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
UTC: 13:57PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia: 23:57PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024
Western Australia, Australia: 21:57PM, Friday, 27 September, 2024


Maybe an associative array is not the best tool here, you could do:
#! /bin/bash -
export TZ
while IFS=: read -r region TZ; do
  printf '%s: %(%H:%M%p, %A, %d %B, %Y)T\n' "$region" -2
done << 'EOF'
Chile:America/Santiago
Tierra Del Fuego:America/Argentina/Ushuaia
...
EOF

Note that -2 for bash printf's %T format directive refers to the time that bash instance was started. That makes sure you get an output for the same time in all regions even if you started the script at 10:46:59.9 and it takes over 0.1 seconds¹ to run.
You can iterate over the keys of an associative arrays in bash with:
for key in "${!assoc[@]}"; do
  value=${assoc[$key]}
  ...
done

But beware the order is non-deterministic.
In zsh², you can get both keys and values at the same time with:
for key value in "${(kv@)assoc}"; do
  ...
done

But there as well, the order is non-deterministic.
Associative arrays are useful to look-up individual values efficiently. There's a higher cost upon assignment as a hash table needs to be built, but the look up is efficient. Here, as you want to loop once over all entries, that completely defeats the purpose and becomes significantly worse both functionally and performance-wise. A normal array would make more sense.
In zsh:
list=(
  'Chile'             America/Santiago
  'Tierra Del Fuego'  America/Argentina/Ushuaia
)
for region TZ in $list; do
  ...
done

Bash doesn't support looping with more than one variable, but you can do:
for (( i = 0; i < ${#list[@]}; i += 2 )); do
  region=${list[i]} TZ=${list[i+1]}
  ...
done

Instead there. Or:
set -- "${list[@]}"
while (( $# )); do
  region=$1 TZ=$2
  ...
  shift 2
done

But that's more cumbersome to write than the CSV heredoc approach mentioned above. Instead of a here doc, you could also have the CSV with the mapping in a separate file which could be maintained separately from the script, and use < /path/to/that/file instead of << 'EOF'...EOF.

¹ Or hours for instance because it's piped to a command that doesn' read its input in a while.
² Where the equivalent of bash printf's %T would be via its strftime builtin (and the $EPOCHSECONDS variable) or prompt expansion like with print -rP -- "$region %D{...}" (though only for the current time with the latter).

Since you want to learn more about associative arrays, have a look at this script, the way you define your associative array is time consuming; that way is more suited to adding new key value pairs to an existing associative array.
I added some formatting to increase the readability of the output.
Wish I got here earlier, the accepted answer built upon things from others... You left them hanging for 20 days, oh well, kudos to them.
Script
Divider="---------------------------------------------"

declare -A Locations

Locations=(
    [Etc/UTC]="UTC"
    [America/Santiago]="Chile"
    [Pacific/Auckland]="New Zealand"
    [Africa/Johannesburg]="South Africa"
    [Atlantic/Stanley]="Falkland Islands"
    [Asia/Dubai]="Port Alfred, Iles Crozet"
    [America/Argentina/Ushuaia]="Tierra Del Fuego"
    [Australia/Perth]="Western Australia, Australia"
    [Australia/Adelaide]="South Australia, Australia"
    [Australia/Melbourne]="VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia"
    [Atlantic/South_Georgia]="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
)

getLocationDateTime() {
    local location label timeDate
    location="$1"
    label="$2"
    timeDate=$(TZ="$location" date "+%H:%M%p, %A, %d %B, %Y")

    echo -e "$label:\n$timeDate\n$Divider" | sed 's#^#  #g'
}


echo -e "\n  Location Date & Times"
echo "  $Divider"

for Location in "${!Locations[@]}"; do
    getLocationDateTime "$Location" "${Locations[$Location]}"
done

echo ''

Output:
It displays fully and much more nicely on the terminal even when not in full screen, the font here is quite big.
 λ bash date.sh 

  Location Date & Times
  ---------------------------------------------
  Port Alfred, Iles Crozet:
  05:25am, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  New Zealand:
  14:25pm, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  Western Australia, Australia:
  09:25am, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  UTC:
  01:25am, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  South Australia, Australia:
  11:55am, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  Chile:
  22:25pm, Wednesday, 16 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands:
  23:25pm, Wednesday, 16 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  VIC, NSW, ACT, and QLD, Australia:
  12:25pm, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  Falkland Islands:
  22:25pm, Wednesday, 16 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  Tierra Del Fuego:
  22:25pm, Wednesday, 16 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------
  South Africa:
  03:25am, Thursday, 17 October, 2024
  ---------------------------------------------

Notes

Associative arrays can also be defined like this

 declare -A assocArr=(
                [key1]=val1
                [key2]=val2
            )


By doing: ${!Locations[@]} we're looping through the keys, this is caused by adding ! so that indirection occurs
Therefore $Location is a key of the associative array
Then we get the value from "${Locations[$Location]}"
When you pass in the key to the array variable of an associative array it's value is returned
The script could've been shorter but I wrote it this way so that it is easy to read and understand, might help others out
Let me know if any questions

On another note you could use the function in the script and just pass in the timezone and location, if you decide you don't want to use an associative array anymore.
